# Cropping of an image in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image

I am trying to crop an image and save the cropped portion as a separate image but I am failing to do as the cropped image is showing blank screen.

PFA the Files.

[image: Original Image][image: Cropped Image]

Below is my code snippet:

```
Dim bmp As Image = pdf.SaveAsImage(pageIndex)
Dim Bmp1 As Bitmap = New Bitmap(bmp)
zoneLeft = Convert.ToInt32((ZonesItems.Item(ClickedZoneCount - 1).ZoneArea.Left * 100) / ZoomPercent)
            zoneWidth = Convert.ToInt32((ZonesItems.Item(ClickedZoneCount - 1).ZoneArea.Width * 100) / ZoomPercent)
            zoneTop = Convert.ToInt32((ZonesItems.Item(ClickedZoneCount - 1).ZoneArea.Top * 100) / ZoomPercent)
            zoneHeight = Convert.ToInt32((ZonesItems.Item(ClickedZoneCount - 1).ZoneArea.Height * 100) / ZoomPercent)


Bmp1.Save("./Bmp1.tiff", Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff)

bmp.Dispose()
bmp = Nothing
```

'X= 388, Y= 81, Width = 144, Height = 22.
    Dim rect As New RectangleF(X, Y, Width, Height)
    Dim Cropped As Bitmap = Bmp1.Clone(rect, Bmp1.PixelFormat)

```
Cropped.Save("./cropped.tiff", Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff)
```

This is how we are calculatin RECT values:

THe above mentioned values are being passed in the Rectangle Function.

Can anyone please let me know what is the issue in my code?

Comment: There are multiple issues with this code. The one that most probably causes a failure is the (missing) definition of  `rect`. Can you post the actual values and show how they are calculated? Also, mind that `Width` and `Height` could be mis-interpreted as the `Width` and `Height` of the current class object, e.g.,when that object is a Form.

Comment: This is the current initialization of rect: `Dim rect As New RectangleF(X, Y, Width, Height)`. Now, what are the **values** of `X`, `Y`, `Width` (bad name) and `Height` (bad name)? They are nowhere to be seen. Also, post the **actual values**. The numeric result of the calculation. Look at them while debugging.

Comment: Values Are taken and passed, The values which I am passing are X= 388, Y= 81, Width = 144, Height = 22.

Comment: TIFF is never not a problem.  That SaveAsImage() call probably generates one with multiple frames.  Neither New Bitmap() nor Bitmap.Clone() will copy all of those frames, you only get the first frame.  Slogging Image.SelectActiveFrame() is required.  Google "how to resize a multi-frame tiff file" to get ahead.

Comment: If the Image you posted is the actual Image and those are the coordinates you're using to create a Rectangle, your cropped area will be a blank (white) area in the middle-top section of the Image, at `Point(388, 81)`, `Size(144, 22)`. In other words, a `144x22` Image taken from the white area between the "Evaluation warnings" and the table header.